# C switch statement with non-compound statement use case?

Tags: c

It is possible to write a C switch statement with a non-compound sub-statement:

```
int x = 2;
int y = 3;

int main()
{
    switch (x)
        y++; // ok

    switch (x)
        case 2: y++; // ok
}
```

Is there any use case for this?  That is, is there ever a reason to use a non-compound sub-statement of a switch statement?

Comment: just asking what's a non-compound sub-statement?

Comment: A switch statement contains one statement: `switch (expr) statement`.  This one statement is the sub-statement.  A compound statement is a statement surrounded by braces and contains a sequence of statements: `{ f(); g(); h(); }`.  Usually a switch is used with a compound sub-statement.  I'm asking if there is ever a use where it is used with a non-compound sub-statement as per my example.

Answer (score 1):

The first switch block in the code doesn't do anything.

When switch statement expression is evaluated, the source code present until the occurrence of matching case label or default label, will be ignored. Hence it doesn't print statement "Before case" in the below program.

```
int x = 2;
int y = 3;

    int main()
    {
        switch (x)
        {
            y++; 
             printf("Before case");
         case 2:
            printf("In case 2");
            break;
         }

       return 0;
    }
```

Output:

```
In case 2
```

Comment: Your statements are all correct, but do not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

"Control passes to the statement whose `case` constant-expression matches the value of `switch` ( expression ). [...] **Execution** of the statement body **begins at the selected statement** and proceeds until the end of the body or until a `break` statement transfers control out of the body." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/)

I don't think the first `switch` does anything... When I compiled it, `y` was 4, which means it only incremented it once.

Comment: That is correct, the first `y++` is not executed - but this does not answer the question.